# Primary key on auto increment when mdf database is cleared

Tags: c#, database, mdf

I removed all data from my mdf database by using delete commands. Now when I run program, the primary key on auto increment does not start from 1. Instead it auto increments the last deleted id number.

The primary key should start from 1 after deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the command [DBCC CheckIdent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

but next time use the TRUNCATE command that deletes the record but resets also the identity

So supposing you have a table named INVOICE and you need to reset its ID to 1

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('INVOICE');
```

and when you want to clear that table use

```
TRUNCATE TABLE INVOICE
```